# Why are the buttons not enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, button, isenabled

On a view controller I created a button which creates 10 other buttons in various positions (with a for loop), and an animation to scale them * 40.

I set the options to make them enabled (true) and showsTouchWhenHighlight but nothing happen when I click on them.

How to make them enabled in order to perform a segue? 
(ps : `button.isEnabled = true` doesn't work).

Comment: How do you know that they are not enabled? Is the action method not being called or it's only that they are not highlighted?

Comment: Could you add some code for us to have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Those button are enabled by default, you haven't added any action to them so nothing happens when you tap them.
When creating them you have to add target to them too, the target will be called. Do you know how to do that?